# How to receive notifications posted via CPDistributedNotificationCenter

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipc

The private `AppSupport` framework on iOS has a class called `CPDistributedNotificationCenter` which appears to support a subset of the functionality provided by `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` on OS X.

I'm attempting to use this class to post notifications from a background daemon such that multiple clients in other processes can receive these notifications and act on them. I realize there are other options, including `CPDistributedMessagingCenter` or `CFMessagePort`, low level mach ports or even darwin's `notify_post`. I'd prefer it if the daemon had no knowledge of the clients however, and I'd like to be able to pass data along with the notification, and `notify_post` does not allow this.

Currently, this is what I am doing in the daemon:

```
CPDistributedNotificationCenter* center;
center = [CPDistributedNotificationCenter centerNamed:@"com.yfrancis.notiftest"];
[center runServer];
[center postNotificationName:@"hello"];
```

And in the client:

```
CPDistributedNotificationCenter* center;
center = [CPDistributedNotificationCenter centerNamed:@"com.yfrancis.notiftest"];
[center startDeliveringNotificationsToMainThread];

NSNotificationCenter* nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[nc addObserver:[Listener new] 
       selector:@selector(gotNotification:)
           name:@"hello"
         object:nil];
```

where `Listener` is a simple class that implements a single method `gotNotification:`

Unfortunately, the client never receives the 'hello' notification. If I replace the `name` argument in the `addObserver` call with `nil` I can see every notification delivered to the client's notification center, but 'hello' is not one of them.

I got the inspiration for my code by looking at a disassembly of `SpringBoard` and `CPDistributedNotificationCenter`. Notifications appear to be delivered via `CPDistributedNotificationCenter`'s `deliverNotification:userInfo:` which acts as a shim for `NSNotificationCenter`'s `postNotificationName:object:userInfo:`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: How about XPC, where each process can maintain a bidirectional connection with the daemon? Or XPC, plus notify_post? The one drawback is that XPC is iOS5+. I would argue that XPC is the new standard for libraries with daemons acting as backends.

Comment: I don't want the daemon to have any knowledge of the clients. XPC defeats that, I just want to fire one-off notifications, and if there are any interested clients they can act on them.

Comment: Activator uses a registration mechanism, `CPDistributedMessagingCenter` requires a remote center name to send messages to, and hence requires knowledge of the client

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out. Your daemon has to wait for a notification indicating that a client has started listening, before sending out your notification. There is no backlog, even if the daemon server runs before the client, there is a registration delay. You can't simply start your server and immediately post notifications to listeners. The following works for me:

In the server init:

```
self.center = [CPDistributedNotificationCenter centerNamed:@"com.yfrancis.notiftest"];
[self.center runServer];

// requires a runloop
NSNotificationCenter* nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[nc addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(clientEvent:)
           name:@"CPDistributedNotificationCenterClientDidStartListeningNotification"
         object:self.center];
```

And make sure to implement the following method in the server:

```
- (void)clientEvent:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    // you can now send notifications to the client that caused this event
    // and any other clients that were registered previously
    [self.center postNotificationName:@"hello!"];
{
```

I've documented this API on the [iPhoneDevWiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CPDistributedNotificationCenter)